# C# COM server , C++ COM Client, call back crashing

Tags: c#, multithreading, boost, com

I have C# COM server and c++ com client. I am doing testing on Windows 2008 R2 and developing on Windows 7.

I have a call back interface for logging declared as follows

```
    public interface ILoggerCallback
    {
        void critical(ref string message);
        void debug(ref string message);
        void error(ref string message);
        void infohigh(ref string message);
        void infolow(ref string message);
        void warning(ref string message);
    }/**/
```

C++ COM client implements the interface (class log_cb) and for now prints everything to console.

```
 HRESULT __stdcall log_cb::raw_infohigh(BSTR* message )
 {  
    wprintf(L"\nwarning: %s", *message);    
    return S_OK;
 }
```

I have created a worker thread in COM Client using boost threads to do the COM initialisation, instance creation etc. 
When the following call back is made in the c#com server

```
 log.infohigh("Successfully initialised server");
```

I have noticed that the log call back fails with this exception  on Windows 2008 R2 test machine but works fine on win7 dev machine

```
C:\TEMP\COMServerTest>SampleCOMClient.exe

Successfully created instance
Unhandled Exception: System.AccessViolationException: Attempted to read or write    protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.
  at System.StubHelpers.InterfaceMarshaler.ConvertToManaged(IntPtr pUnk, IntPtr itfMT, IntPtr classMT, Int32 flags)
```

I tried this with windows threading and it works fine. 
Mere inclusion of

```
#include "boost/thread.hpp"
```

causes this error.

Could anyone explain me what is happening here. 
Many thanks.

Comment: Does the interface have the right attributes for COM?

Comment: Yes it does. The worker thread works as expected when I use windows threads instead of boost.